# Remove on screen menu bar gpe 4.4.4

Tags: htc-one

I have an htc one

Its rooted/s-off

I've installed a Google Play Edition 4.4.4 rom

(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2788150)

I now get the ugly on screen menu bar for some apps (for example doodle jump)

I think this is generally referred to as the 'three dots menu'

I have tried to remove it by installing the teaMseven kernel, and mapping logo2menu and using the option to remove the three dot menu.

(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2307371)

Upon reboot I have the logo2menu enabled, but I still have the onscreen menu/nav bar at the bottom

This method used to work on GPE 4.4.2

Does anyone know any other way to remove it?

Given that I do have a menu button mapped it is completely redundant!

(This is a screen print of what I mean:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/105735777895163400841/posts/5hXhAv53DMH?pid=6064198061488324082&oid=105735777895163400841)

thanks